# Cannot assign a value to a dynamically created list

Tags: python

I understand that I can't declare the dimension of a list with Python like other languages (e.g. `listx(8)` to create a list with 8 elements).

So, I am declaring the list as:

```
listx = [None] * 8
```

It works when issuing the commands interactively in the Python console:

```
>>> listx = [None] * 8
>>> listx
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> listx[4] = 'X'
>>> listx
[None, None, None, None, 'X', None, None, None]
```

But if I code the same inside a program, it shows an error when assigning a value to an element of the list:

[image]

How can I fix this? I need to create a huge multi-dimensional matrix dynamically and fill the cells inside the program.

Comment: This is only a warning from a static type analysis performed by your IDE. You should be able to switch it off somehow or start learning about type analysis and type annotations. Personally I would recommend to do the former but this is just an opinion.

Comment: *"I need to create a huge multi-dimensional matrix dynamically"* - Maybe NumPy would be better

Comment: What IDE are you using? This seems like a bug in its type checking.

Comment: @Barmar I was just thinking, it's weird that it's flagging the `4`. I guess it's naively treating the assignment as `listx.__setitem__(4, 'X')` (which is what happens under the hood) and type-checking that.

Comment: @wjandrea - I didn't catch that. That is strange. I never use type-checking with python so I'm not intimately familiar with these warnings.

Comment: To be clear, you can't directly declare a `list` with fixed contents *because you almost never need to*. If you explain what you're doing, odds are the `list` can probably be built dynamically, either with `.append` as needed, or via a list comprehension that seeds it with some mutation of provided data. I'm not saying there is *never* a reason to define a `list` of specific size up front, but it's quite unusual, and almost never a performance benefit like people think it is (at least in part because Python is actually pretty terrible, on overhead:useful-work ratio, at indexing).

Comment: @wjandrea I checked it against Pylance: After looking the `builtin.pyi` file, I saw that two `@overload`s are define: `def __setitem__(self, __key: SupportsIndex, __value: _T) -> None: ...` and the second one which has slice object. that `SupportsIndex` is a `Protocol` which defines `__index__`. Looks like Pylance(pyright indeed) can't see int's `__index__`. Even with a custom object with `__index__` it still complains. I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error but a warning from your IDE (I am guessing PyCharm).

If you know that it is going to be a list of strings you can do:

```
listx = [''] * 8
listx[4] = 'X'
```

And the warning will go away.

---

You can also specify the type of the variable when creating it using type hint:

```
listx: list[str] = [''] * 8
listx[4] = 'X'
```

Or if you want the list to contain *different types* of objects you can use:

```
listx: list[object] = [None] * 8
listx[4] = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE automatically runs a static typechecker on your code. While your code is fine, if you wish your IDE doesn't give a false positive, you can add a type annotation:

```
listx: list[str | None] = [None] * 8
listx[4] = 'X'
```

This tells the type checker that `listx` is a list of items that can each be either a `str` or `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do nothing. Code will be executed well. It's just a warning from your IDE. You can try to turn this checking off.

Or you can use type hints

```py
listx: list[None | str] = [None] * 8
listx[4] = 'X'
```

This way we show IDE, that our variable's `listx` type is a list, which consists of None-s and strings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. In my case I need to define a three-dimensional array (50x50x50) that can receive any type of object. With your help it could be solved with:

```
items: list[list[list[object]]] = [[[None] * 50 for _ in range(50)] for _ in range(50)]
```